# Division operator not working as expected (swift)

Tags: swift, operators, swiftui, division, swift5

I need to calculate the probability of something, and the division operator is not working at all and it just return zero. 
I can't understand the problem because I tried other operators(*,+,-) and they all work completely fine and return true results.

here is the code:

```
   Button(action: {

                    self.winner2 = self.diceNames.randomElement()!
                    self.winner1 = self.diceNames.randomElement()!
                    self.rollCount += 1

                    if self.winner1 == self.winner2  {
                        self.pair = self.pairDice
                        self.pairCount += 1
                    }else{
                        self.pair = ""
                    }

                    self.pairChance = Double(self.pairCount / self.rollCount)*100
                    print("\(self.pairChance)")
                })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dividing two integers, so [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers) is used. To avoid this, you could explicitly cast the operands to `Double`s:

```
self.pairChance = Double(self.pairCount) / Double(self.rollCount) * 100.0
```